# Best way to pass and get multiple values for same parameter via URL in PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking into what is the best way to pass multiple values for the same parameter name via URL in PHP and then get those results.

Example:

`http://www.example.com?color=blue&color=red&color=green`

For some reason all the answers I can find is for other programing languages...

Comment: You'd have to "pack", eg. like `?color=red,green,blue` and then explode it on the server side `explode(',', $_GET['color'])`

Comment: What is the standard? Doing that "pack" or pass them as array like the Ashu example?

Comment: Ashus approach is better in my opinion, because it's cleaner and uses the standarized, official way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass them as an array

```
 http://www.example.com?color[]=blue&color[]=red&color[]=green
```

On server side use `$_GET['color'],` which should return an array

```
print_r($_GET['color']); // Array ( [0] => green [1] => red [2] => blue )
```

Comment: Sounds great, I think this solves my problem. Side question Is it also possible to make this type of url seo friendly like example.com/colors/blue/red/green via .htaccess?